# Как изменить иконку узла JTree исходя из значения листов?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

Вот пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исходя из успешности выполнения тестовых методов должна меняться иконка у узла, представляющего класс, в котором эти тестовые методы написаны. То есть на классе TestMyAssert должен быть крестик, если в классе выполнились все методы - должна быть галочка. Как я понял, сначала отрисовываются узлы, а потом уже листья в JTree.

Рисовальщик у меня такой:

```
class RedTreeCellRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 707287337017494764L;

@Override
public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row,
        boolean hasFocus) {
    super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, isSelected, expanded,
            leaf, row, hasFocus);
    setForeground(getTextSelectionColor());
    DefaultMutableTreeNode treenode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) value;
    Object ob;
    if (leaf) {
        ob = treenode.getUserObject();
        if (((MyTreeLeaf) ob).getMessanger().isFailed()) {
            setIcon(new ImageIcon("images/redkrest.png"));
        } else if (((MyTreeLeaf) ob).getMessanger().isFailure()) {
            setIcon(new ImageIcon("images/blueminus.png"));
        } else {
            setIcon(new ImageIcon("images/green.png"));
        }
    }
    return this;
}
}
```

У меня был только один вариант: взять родителя и установить соответствующую иконку ему. Пробовал так:

```
treenode.getParent();
```

Но этот метод возвращает объект класса TreeNode, а у него нет метода `setIcon()`

Comment: Допишите в вашем renderer ветку `else`, и смотрите, что там у детей `treenode`

Comment: @zRrr, правильно я понял что в else нужно будет организовать цикл и для всех листьев каждого узла посмотреть, какие у них значения?